# Graph Search changes: why did Facebook do this?

Tags: search, facebook

Recently I noticed a little change in the Graph Search UI. It went from this (plain):

[image: plain]

to this (more pronounced search field):

[image: pronouced]

Even though it had the same text "Type to search for people, places and things", how does making it look more like search field help ?

Comment: Apparently it does not have the same text. Are the two images capture when the search bar is in focus?

Comment: @GildasFrémont Actually the first one was pulled from Google Images .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this in a [blog note](http://blog.jadjoubran.com/2013/04/graph-search-ab-testing.html). No idea if its any trustful though:

> **Graph Search A/B Testing**
>
> Facebook is doing some A/B testing on their Graph Search.
>
> They are testing their Original layout, vs 2 new layouts (A & B).
>
> A few weeks from now, we should be able to see the declared winner (if
>   any).

[image]

**Apparently Facebook is testing your hypothesis**: Making search field look more like search field helps. Help what, that I do not know.

An [interview](http://techcrunch.com/2013/02/15/the-history-behind-facebooks-graph-search/) with Rasmussen (Graph Search PO) tends to confirm it is A/B testing:

> Facebook Graph Search has yet to roll out to all users, and Rasmussen
>   writes that part of the reason for the partial rollout so far was to
>   allow live A/B testing on real users — a process that circumvents the
>   possibility of endless internal discussions. “Without live usage we’d
>   just be arguing all day,” he writes.

Comment: love this part: "a process that circumvents the possibility of endless internal discussions. “'Without live usage we’d just be arguing all day,'”

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that one of the things that is being A/B testing here is whether or not users recognize that this is a search field.  The magnifying glass icon is a classic bit of iconography for search.  Will this element be prominent as a 'search box' without the prominence of the magnifying glass icon?

I suspect that Facebook is interested in defining their brand as the iconography for social graph searching, and thus wish to 'displace' the magnifying glass icon in the minds of users